# How to bind a select and radiobutton with json?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json with a series of options that I want to link to this select and this radiobutton that I have in this form.
What I want is that when I select any of the radiobutton options, I can only choose a series of json options (for example, if it is a man that appears single or if it is a woman that appears as an option that is single, said in a feminine way), the problem is that I am unable to make it work, below I pass part of the code including the json

HTMl:

```html
<!-- Sexo -->
<input type="Radio" name="Hombre" id="Hombre">Hombre
<input type="Radio" name="Mujer" id="Mujer">Mujer<br></br>
    
<li>
    <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil</label>
    <select id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil">
    </select>
</li><br>
```

JSON:

```json
{
  "Estados": {
    "tipoPersona": "Hombre",
    "estado_civil": [
      {
        "codEstado": "S",
        "estado": "Soltero",
        "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "C",
        "estado": "Casado",
        "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "D",
        "estado": "Divorciado",
        "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "V",
        "estado": "Viudo",
        "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
      }
    ]
  },
  "tipoPersona": "Mujer",
  "estado_civil": [
    {
      "codEstado": "S",
      "estado": "Soltera",
      "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
    },
    {
      "codEstado": "C",
      "estado": "Casada",
      "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
    },
    {
      "codEstado": "D",
      "estado": "Divorciada",
      "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
    },
    {
      "codEstado": "V",
      "estado": "Viuda",
      "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
    }
  ]
}
```

And javascript:

```js
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var myObj = eval( "("+this.responseText+")");
        console.log(myObj);
        
        var arraymembers = myObj.estados;
        
        var contenido="";

        arraymembers.forEach(element =>{
            console.log(element.tipoPersona);

            var th = document.createElement("th");
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            contenido = "tipoPersona"+element.tipoPersona+"codEstado"+element.tipoPersona;
            var txtContenido = document.createTextNode(contenido);
            tr.appendChild(txtContenido);
            th.appendChild(tr); 

            document.getElementById("estado_civil").appendChild(th);
        });
    }

}

xmlhttp.open("GET","file:///F:/javascript%20recuperacion/ejercicio%20formulario/generated.json",true);
    
xmlhttp.send();
```

the rest of the code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvjt7y28/1/

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code, I see that in your JSON the key is `Estados` (with a capital e) but in the processing code you assign `arraymembers = myObj.estados` (with a lower case e). Could it be as simple as a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some issues in your code:

- You try to append table rows (`tr`) to table head cells (`th`) and then append these cells to a `select` tag. Which doesn't make sense because the cells should be added to the row and, more important, you aren't using a table. Therefor they should be `option` tags.
- Your json is not correctly formatted: You aren't closing the json object and "Estados" (missing closing curly brackets).
- "Estados" should be an array of objects over which you can iterate (`arraymembers.forEach`).
- "Estados" shouldn't have a Capital letter at the beginning or you should call it with `myObj.Estados`
- Your radio buttons have no value, just name and id.

**Working example**:

Since i can't use your ajax request (cross origin policy) i hardcoded the data as a var for demonstrating the solution.

```js
let data = {
  "Estados": [{
    "tipoPersona": "Hombre",
    "estado_civil": [
      {
        "codEstado": "S",
        "estado": "Soltero",
        "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "C",
        "estado": "Casado",
        "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "D",
        "estado": "Divorciado",
        "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "V",
        "estado": "Viudo",
        "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "tipoPersona": "Mujer",
    "estado_civil": [
      {
        "codEstado": "S",
        "estado": "Soltera",
        "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "C",
        "estado": "Casada",
        "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "D",
        "estado": "Divorciada",
        "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
      },
      {
        "codEstado": "V",
        "estado": "Viuda",
        "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
      }
    ]
  }]
};

var arraymembers = data.Estados;
arraymembers.forEach(element => {

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  var contenido = "tipoPersona" + element.tipoPersona + "codEstado" + element.tipoPersona;
  option.innerHTML = contenido;

  document.getElementById("estado_civil").appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<!-- Sexo -->
<input type="Radio" name="Hombre" id="Hombre" value="Hombre">Hombre
<input type="Radio" name="Mujer" id="Mujer" value="Mujer">Mujer<br></br>

<li>
  <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil</label>
  <select id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil">
  </select>
</li>
```

---

In your question you describe a complete different result that you desire than your code produces. I think you want the options to be "Single", "Maried" etc. (in your example "Soltero", "Casado" etc.) for male or female.

To achieve that goal you have to:

- give the two objects of "Estados" a name (for example "Hombre" and "Mujer") and let "Estados" be an object (like you did in your example).
- give the two radio buttons the same name (for example "Sexo") for selecting only one of them.
- add an event listener (incl. handler) for each radio button
- grab the selected value in that handler and select with it the inner object of "Estados" (gender: "Hombre" or "Mujer").
- grab the object "estados_civil" in that inner object, iterate over it, create an `option` tag and fill it with the data ("estado") that you want to be visible as option in the `select` tag
- delete all options at the beginning of each click (reset before inserting new options)

**Working example**:

```js
let data = {
  "Estados": {
    "Hombre": {
      "tipoPersona": "Hombre",
      "estado_civil": [
        {
          "codEstado": "S",
          "estado": "Soltero",
          "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "C",
          "estado": "Casado",
          "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "D",
          "estado": "Divorciado",
          "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "V",
          "estado": "Viudo",
          "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
        }
      ]
    },
    "Mujer": {
      "tipoPersona": "Mujer",
      "estado_civil": [
        {
          "codEstado": "S",
          "estado": "Soltera",
          "descripcion": "Que no está unido en matrimonio a otra persona"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "C",
          "estado": "Casada",
          "descripcion": "Casado es el estado civil que adquiere una persona en el momento que contrae matrimonio"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "D",
          "estado": "Divorciada",
          "descripcion": "Que está separado de aquello a lo que está o debería estarunido o con lo que está o debería estar relacionado"
        },
        {
          "codEstado": "V",
          "estado": "Viuda",
          "descripcion": " Que ha perdido, por fallecimiento, a su cónyuge y que no ha vuelto a casarse."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=Sexo]');
for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("estado_civil").innerHTML = '';
    var sexo = this.value;
    var estados = data.Estados[sexo].estado_civil;
    for (j = 0; j < estados.length; j++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.innerHTML = estados[j].estado;

      document.getElementById("estado_civil").appendChild(option);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Sexo -->
<input type="Radio" name="Sexo" id="Hombre" value="Hombre">Hombre
<input type="Radio" name="Sexo" id="Mujer" value="Mujer">Mujer<br></br>

<li>
  <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil</label>
  <select id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil">
  </select>
</li>
```